# Is it a good practice to always return a Result<T, E> from functions?

Tags: rust

I realize that I always use `Result` when I need to return something from a function.

Is it something usual in a good Rust development? And should I also return a `Result` for a `void` function that might encounter an error (like `Result<(), Error>`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Result<T, E>` should be always returned by "error-prone" functions, but not necessarily all functions.

[`std::fs::read_to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html), for example, returns a `Result` because of the possibility of various errors occurring. [`vec.len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.len), on the other hand, is guaranteed to not raise an error (and as such directly returns a `usize` instead of a `Result`).

As for your second question, you're absolutely correct: error-prone (but non-value-returning) functions should return a `Result<(), Error>`.

Comment: What is an "error prone" function? You only need to return `Result<T, E>` if you are either 1) calling functions that can return errors themselves and you are not going to handle them within the function or 2) generating your own errors due to certain conditions (eg, when creating a public API)

Comment: Swap "error-prone" for "fallible" and its much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Returning `Result` is very common in Rust.

In practice, this can often be shortened to `Result<T>` instead of `Result<T, E>`. I'm not saying that's always a good idea, but in many cases it is and can save some typing. Here is an example with the `anyhow`'s [`Result`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.0/anyhow/type.Result.html) type:

```
pub type Result<T, E = Error> = core::result::Result<T, E>;
```

If you have a "void" function that could return an error, you can declare the function as returning `Result<()>`.